# How best to transfer NSManagedObjects from iPhone to Watch

Tags: core-data, swift2, ios9, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I'm re-creating my app from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2 and in the former I used shared groups etc.

I'm now trying to use the new WatchConnectivity and have come up against a major brick wall..!!

On the phone I have the app working downloading json and populating into NSManagedObjects in my data store and everything works perfect...on the phone.

I foolishly though I could use the session.updateApplicationContext(dictionary) approach.....but have now found out

1. I have to use NSCoding
2. NSCoding and NSManagedObjects are not a good match!

So, could I ask how is the preferred way in iOS9 and Swift 2 to transfer CoderData data from the phone to the watch?

Taking note that the watch has no need to modify, update etc the data as this all happens on the phone.  The watch simply displays it.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new temporary store with `NSBinaryStoreType` type, and cloning `NSManagedObject`s to transfer into new store.
2. Save temporary store.
3. Use `[WCSession transferFile:metadata:]` to temporary file, or use `[WCSession updateApplicationContext:]` or other transfer methods with `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:]`.

Primary reason to use `NSBinaryStoreType` is that it will take smallest file size among the supported types.

The second reason is that `NSSQLiteStoreType` will needs additional `shm` and `wal` files by default. It makes core-data fast, however it requires tricky handling and takes more file size.

---

PS. What if you decided to use `[WCSession transferFile:metadata:]`, You must delete temporary file after finishing transfer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but over the weekend I had a "lightbulb" moment that removed the need (for now) to pass any CoreData objects!  I realised that I only need to send the text of the managed object  that is to appear in the list on the watch and the id (not the managedobjectid) for when the user taps on a given row.  The watch then does another call and request the text to display the details of that selected object.  I guess as I was using CoreData I presumed I needed to use it across to the watch too....but not so!  Thanks for replying tho, have voted you up on that basis.

Comment: It's glad to hear that you've found own solution. I think that you may should consider not reachable(or cloud connected) condition. Typical watch app caches data itself to provide offline using.

Comment: Thanks ;-) I now have it working correctly using the Interactive Messaging as this works immediately.  So I can now just send over a dictionary containing just the string values I'm interested in, the watch does not need the managed objects so this works.  Taken me a while but got there!